# How to test a bunch of video files if they are playable?

Tags: video, video-streaming, testdisk

I would like to test my video files which have been recovered by Photorec. Some of the video files have errors. So I want to test them all at once to see if they can be played.

For example, a video file's time "1h30m" had been recovered, but I can just play the first 5 minutes. I get an error after those 5 minutes. `Sorry, this video cannot be played.` It also gives me a streaming error when using another player. *I don't recall the exact error message.*

1. I want to re-order as directories which are called "playable and
   not-playable".
2. If there is a another way to recover videos, please share your
   opinion with me.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that first point about re-ordering directories. Would you care to explain? As for the second point, I can tell you that you can use Recuva to restore all file types, not just videos or pictures.

Comment: As for the original problem, I suggest you create a backup for the next time this happens. When it happens again, you will be prepared to restore the files from backup and you can skip this recovery step altogether.

Comment: Since an error can occur anywhere in the video, an obvious solution is to watch each one all the way through, maybe using some type of grid to dispaly many at once.  Are you talking about just evaluating ones the recovery software says were not successfully recovered, or are you looking for some way to evaluate each video programatically to detect whether it contains any errors?  You apparently already know that some contain errors, so whether or not they are playable would seem to require playing.

Comment: I want to seperate it as 2 directory and 1. directory is called playable 2.directory is called broken-videos. I have archives of movies. There are a LOT of mp4 files(about 1000). And some video doesn't playable after x mins later.

Comment: Yes I am looking for a programatically way to do this.

Comment: To your point #2: you have already recovered the files.  Are you talking about using a different file recovery program on the original media to see if it can recover the files in better condition, or some type of video editing/repair software that can restore the damaged files to playable condition?

Comment: If it is possible to repair it, it will be better than others options. But if not, is there any program which is better than Photorec.

Comment: Photorec is a respected program.  Sammyg mentioned Recuva, which is another (free), highly regarded program.  These programs can only recover the data that's there; there isn't much they can do about data that was previously corrupted, or cross-linked files, etc.  If Photorec recovered files, it's pretty likely that any other program that was able to recover the same files would recover the same data.

Comment: Yes I also think like that. My hdd is 1 TB so re-scanning it will take LOTs of time (With Photorec it takes about 4 days.

Comment: My hdd corrupts suddenly so I didn't write any data after corrupts. When I watching a video from hdd using laptop, it suddenly cut the power off for usb. After that I can't open hdd using windows explorer but testdisk recovered some files with their orginal name. So I used Photorec for others.

Comment: VirtualDub has a "scan video for errors" function, but it will only spot the worst of the errors, and any video ending abruptly you would have to know the original length. Spot checking (using standard player) and virtualdub scan for errors, you could get some seperation going , but without watching them all, Fixers idea,  firing up 12 videos at once and watching them at 2X speed using a render method that is easy on the cpu/gpu requirments, would get them fully checked.